# Sound card CD audio in connector

Tags: connector, identification, sourcing

The typical name I see given is MPC, MPC2, or MPC-2, and the cables are readily available, but I can't seem to source the female PCB-side connector. Obviously, a 1x4 pin header would work just fine, but I'd like to use the locking connector if possible.

This is what the cable looks like:

[image]
<sub>(source: [connectworld.net](https://www.connectworld.net/cdepot/images/jpeg/L71515.jpg))</sub>

Comment: You mean the male PCB connector?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Updated link**

Is [this](http://www.digikey.com/scripts/DkSearch/dksus.dll?wt.z_header=search_go&lang=en&keywords=5-103639-3&x=0&y=0&cur=USD) what you're looking for?

Part number 5-103639-3 from TE connectivity

[image]

Comment: Awesome, thanks! This is the horizontal version for others looking: http://octopart.com/70553-0003-molex-29645